# Crane Clan ability when they tie, but another faction would win

Tags: battle-for-rokugan

In the situation where the Crane clan partakes in a battle, don't win said battle but still tie due to there being more than one opponent or the province being neutral with a standing defense, do they then win that province? The Crane Clans power reads "When you are tied, you win instead". For example in the following example who wins:

Crane and Scorpion attack a neutral Shadowlands province (which has a plus one defence printed on it), Scorpion with an Army 3 token and Crane with an Army 1 token.

Because Crane has the same value as the province and tie, do they win the province? RAW it would seem to be the case but it also doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me? As if the bonus should only come into effect if the Crane clan is tieing the highest opponent. Is there any kind of FAQ or designer statement that clears this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability is definitely poorly worded. When you are tied you win refers to tie breaking, so while you would win the tie, that does not guarantee you the province win. The ability is meant to override the standard defender wins ties rules, making it easier for crane clan to win on attacks by simply tying the defense. The tie must be a tie for the win to win the province.

See discussion on [BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1913678/clarification-crane-power).

Answer (score 0):

In your question, Crane ties with the shadowlands defense, but is also tied for the lowest score. Scorpion beats Crane and the native shadowlands defense and wins the province.

More generally, when Crane ties, Crane wins. It's pretty clear. Let's say a Dragon province is attacked by Crane and Unicorn. If Unicorn attacks with 3, Crane attacks with 3, and Unicorn defends with 3 (or any value equal to or less than 3), Crane wins.

Comment: I'm afraid this is unhelpful. In the example given in the question I'm asking what happens if Crane ties while someone else would win anyway. After discussing this on other forums I now treat the rules as "If Crane would tie with the strongest force, they win the tie"

Comment: That is when crane ties for the win, this is ashing when crane ties for second place or lower

Comment: Sorry, I read your post a little too quickly. I'll edit mine to answer your question directly, and not the general question that I seemed to have answered when there is a three-way conflict and crane is involved.